# Про строковую переменную

Tags: типы, переменные

Есть переменная типа String... в ней какие то символы... как узнать, какие это символы?
Еще проще сказать... есть ли в переменной число с плавающей точкой или там что то другое...

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что нужно понять - это то, что нельзя найти то, чего не знаешь. В данном случае код не сможет найти то, чего он не знает.
Поэтому, нужно создать фильтра-правила, которые применять к строке и смотреть.
Например, самое простое правило  - ни одного символа -пустая строка.
Или все цифры - значит натуральное число.
Точно также можно создать правила для большего. Даже вплоть до того, что если первый не пробельный символ - <, значит это может быть xml, направляем xml парсер.
Помогут тут регулярные выражения, лексические парсеры (гуглить "книгу дракона" и все что с ней связано), и конечно много воображения и смекалки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет
[Динамическая идентификация типа данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Не поможет. Вопрос не о том немного.

Comment: А простите. Не так понял.

Answer (score 0):

Брать посимвольно и проверять. Для этого в языках есть много интересного, начиная от обращения к символу в строке как элементу символьного массива, заканчивая регулярными выражениями и грамматиками.